# How do I just generate a panel with r^2 values using the corrgram function in r?

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to make a correlogram with points and r^2 values, but I cannot seem to exclude the confidence intervals in the `panel.conf` command.

```
corrgram(x, order = FALSE, lower.panel=panel.pts, upper.panel = panel.conf, diag.panel = panel.density)
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. That will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

On some sample data:

```
set.seed(111)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100, 5, 1),
                 b = rnorm(100, 2, 1),
                 c = rnorm(100, 3, 1))

corrgram(df, 
         order = FALSE, 
         lower.panel = panel.pts, 
         upper.panel = panel.cor, 
         diag.panel = panel.density,
         col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("black")))
```

[image]